# How to add attachment (with code coverage details) in build notification email in Team Foundatuon server 2017

Tags: plugins, tfs, azure-devops

Hi we have some requirement.

We have to send code coverage and Verascan details as an attachment in build notification emails in Team Foundation Server 2017.

Can someone help me to achieve this functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use some custom tasks to send mails in the build definition such as [send email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) or [email](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Email) task.

With attachments which allows for a comma separated list of attachments to be added to the email, and this is where you would attach your code coverage report.

A sample for your reference: [Custom VSTS Task: Code Analysis & Email](http://totalalm.azurewebsites.net/2015/12/11/custom-vsts-task-code-analysis/)