# How to send code coverage and tests(Failed and Passed) count on an email after VSTS successful build?

Tags: .net, build, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

We are using VSTS as continuous interaction tool to deploy build and the application is built on ASP.NET Web API and Angular 4.

I have configured successful build but not able find any detail about sending details email after a successful build.

I need to send code coverage and unit tests count after each build.

Is there any way to send a detailed email on VSTS?

Note: Currently I'm using sendgrid email plugin to send an email.

Answer (score 1):

You could [configure the default Notifications to send notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-personal-notifications?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for the events like Build Success/Failure/Cancel,likewise for deployment and much more.

For sending the code coverage results, you may use custom [Send Email Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask#overview)  by attaching your code coverage reports.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43511922/7073340)